# A Question about what it means to Compare two Vectors

Tags: complexity-theory, terminology

Please consider the following question:
Given an integer m by n matrix A and an integer m-vector b, the 0-1 integer programming problem asks whether there exists an integer n-vector x with elements in the set ${ 0, 1 }$ such that $Ax \leq b$. Prove that 0-1 integer programming is
NP-complete.

Am I correct that $Ax$ is a vector, $b$ is a vector and $Ax \leq b$ is true iff every element of $Ax$ is less than or equal to its corresponding element of $b$?

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, element-wise comparison is the usual convention for these constraint problems.